# Запись в JSON дублируется

Tags: php, json

Вот файл со скриптом `php`.Помогите, как сделать так что бы из `$users` сделать `$users= array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'pass' => $password);` что бы переменная id была счетчиком, начиналась с нуля и при каждой записи увеличивалась.Буду очень благодарен за подсказки.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
if(!isset($name, $password) || empty($name) || empty($password)){
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}
$file = "../data/users.json";
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$users = array('name' => $name, 'pass' => $password);

if(isset($users[$name])) {
    if($users[$name] != $password){
        http_response_code(400);
    }
} 
else {
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Comment: `$users[$name] = $password;` что же это такое

Comment: @etki прошу прощение за мою не внимательность. У нас уже 3 часа ночи)

Comment: объясните конкретнее, вы хотите поднять массив из файла, добавить в него нового пользователя и положить новый массив в файл, так что-бы он был про нумерован?

Comment: @Dr.McMy да, именно это я и хочу

Comment: @Dr.McMy а не могли бы вы мне подсказать, у меня не работает проверка на присутствие в файле имени.Я до этого не использовал в $users 'name'  и 'pass', а теперь проверка перестала работать.

Comment: поправил ответ, в цикле, когда в новый массив добавляете новый элемент, используйте переменную $user['name']  как ключ для $new_users[ $user['name'] ], а при вызове скрипта заново установите ваше старое условие на проверку наличия имени в массиве по ключу состоящего из этого самого имени)

Comment: @Dr.McMy странно, но не работает(я уверен что я что то не так сделал)

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60557/discussion-between-mbmenes-and-dr-mc-my).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял, то вам стоит добавить в массив нового пользователя при помощи этого (внимание на квадратные скобки):

```
$users[] = array('name' => $name, 'pass' => $password);
```

далее перебрать массив циклом foreach в новый массив примерно так:

```
$new_users = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($users as $key => $user) {
    $new_user = '';
    $new_user = $user;
    $new_user['id'] = $i;
    $new_users[ $user['name'] ] = $new_user;
    $i++;
}
```

Чтобы проверить наличие имени просто перед добавлением спросите ваш старый вариант

```
if(isset($users[$name])) {
    // что-то
}
```

Comment: [В каких случаях пишется «чтобы» и «что бы»](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/v-kakih-sluchayah-pishetsya-chtobyi-i-chto-byi.html)